# Obtain OAuth2 Access Token for Dropbox Core API with Codenameone's Oauth2 Class

Tags: oauth-2.0, dropbox, codenameone

I'm trying to use codenameone's Oauth2 Class to obtain an access token for Dropbox's Core API. The code I'm using is as follows:

```
Oauth2 auth = new Oauth2("https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize", "<APP KEY>", "https://www.google.com", "");
    Oauth2.setBackToParent(true);
    auth.showAuthentication(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            //get authentication token
            System.out.println(evt.getSource());
        }
    });
```

When I run my app in the simulator, I'm presented with a web component that contains the log-in page for the OAuth2 authentication (like it's supposed to) but when I complete the sign-in process, The app does not return to the parent view and my action listener is not triggered.

The process is actually working because I'm getting a message that indicates that my app has been added to my dropbox account, however my app is not able to retrieve the token because my action listener isn't being triggered.

I've looked everywhere on the internet for a solution to this problem and can't find anything. I found one other article on SO that was asking the same question but wasn't seeming to get an acceptable answer as well. It seems that the only good documentation for the Oauth Class provided by codenameone is the codenameone API Doc and it doesn't provide very good examples for how to use their classes.

If anyone could help that would be greate

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Dropbox cn1lib - http://www.codenameone.com/blog/drop-it-introducing-dropbox-integration

Comment: Can you upload files with the drop box lib? Also do you know where i can find good documentation for it? Id like to be able to see a list of classes and methods that are included in this library and I can't seem to find any anywhere

Comment: You can't, but the OAuth should be working there and you can use that as a reference since the library is open source. You can also contribute your improvements to said library to help other community members.