# Dropbox OAuth2 authorize API is not redirecting as expected

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, dropbox-api

I'm attempting to connect to the [Dropbox API using OAuth2](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#oa2-authorize). I'm using [DropNet](https://github.com/DropNet/DropNet) as the client library and using the Token (implicit grant) flow option. The test code (roughly the same as `DropNet.Samples.WinForms`) is a simple dialog with an embedded browser control to display the API login page.

The problem I'm seeing is that the API does not redirect the browser to the specified redirect URL (`http://localhost`). After I provide my credentials and click Allow to grant access, instead of being redirected to localhost I'm redirected to `https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize_submit`, which fails to load (error 404). There are also no query parameters on the redirected URL. I'm expecting to be redirected to localhost with query parameters containing an authorization code.

For reference the login URL is: `https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=<blah>&redirect_uri=http://localhost`.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? The behavior looks very similar to what's described in: [Obtain OAuth2 Access Token for Dropbox Core API with Codenameone's Oauth2 Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734460/obtain-oauth2-access-token-for-dropbox-core-api-with-codenameones-oauth2-class), but there's no direct answer there.

Comment: The redirect URI should be specified in the redirect_uri parameter on /oauth2/authorize: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#oa2-authorize Are you supplying that to /oauth2/authorize?

Comment: Yup, I supplied the redirect URL and verified that it's in the query string to the authorize call.

Comment: Can you post a sample /authorize URL?

Comment: Thanks for the input - I added the URL to the question. I also noticed that the client library (DropNet) was using **api**.dropbox.com instead of **www**.dropbox.com, which I think was also wrong, but that's fixed now.

Comment: Thanks! The sample looks right. Is JavaScript enabled in the embedded browser? (It needs to be if not.) If it is, are you getting any JavaScript errors in the console?

Comment: I'll check the JavaScript console - I don't think it's disabled but it still may provide a clue.

Answer (score 1):

[edited]
I still don't know why it isn't working to use `http://localhost` as the redirect URL, but I switched to using `https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/redirect_receiver` as recommended by @Greg, and it works correctly now.

In case it affects other people trying to use the DropNet WinForms sample code, I also had to adjust the code to handle the `Navigating` and `Navigated` events in the embedded browser, in addition to `DocumentCompleted`, because the browser behavior seems to vary by OS and browser version (not a big surprise). The code also needs to be smart enough to stop navigating once it detects the redirect because the browser may continue navigation from that point.

Originally I had fixed it by redirecting to Google, but as @smarks pointed out, this is not a good idea.

Comment: Glad to hear it's working now, though I believe it should have worked with http://localhost anyway. If it helps Dropbox does have this page for this purpose: https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/redirect_receiver

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about that redirect_receiver page - that seems like exactly what I want. I'll try with that and see how it works, and update the answer with this info.

Comment: "That being said, using Google as the redirect URL might be a bad thing to do, since I'm basically sending them my token. They wouldn't have my API key to use it with, of course, but it still seems iffy." API keys are public knowledge, and you don't need one to use an access token anyway. The actual access token goes in the URL fragment, so it's not sent directly to the target server, but JavaScript on the page could access it, so you're right to consider this a security risk. (`redirect_receiver` is a good option)

Comment: Thanks for the info @smarx - that makes sense. I'll make sure to call this out in the answer edits.