# Codename One: How to read/write to Dropbox?

Tags: oauth, dropbox, codenameone

I am trying to write an app using Codename One that can read/write to Dropbox.

I noted that the Dropbox add-in uses **OAuth 1.0**, and the access to Dropbox is read-only, which is not useful for what I want to do.

Are there plans in CN1 to implement Dropbox read/write ability?

This is critical for CN1 to be useful for this application.

Answer (score 1):

Codename One has a Dropbox SDK which is based on OAuth 1.0.

You can implement it to store and retrieve files to and from Dropbox.

There's a full blog about it [here](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/drop-it-introducing-dropbox-integration.html) and you can view the source project on GitHub [here](https://github.com/chen-fishbein/dropbox-codenameone-sdk), it may be a little old and there might be a newer version.

The good thing is that, it's open source...so you can also contribute to it.

Comment: AFAIK this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734460/obtain-oauth2-access-token-for-dropbox-core-api-with-codenameones-oauth2-class?s=5|3.2055 was trying to build write functionality into the dropbox implementation. He didn't contribute the changes or update us on the status though, would be nice to have write support